# App Center Builds for multiple project configurations

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center

I have setup a number of solution configurations in my Xamarin Forms solution such as Test, Training, Prod. The idea is each configuration represents an app environment that doesn't interfere with the other environments. So users can practically have all the different environments installed on the same device.

For iOS, each configuration has its own unique bundle id and a provisioning profile. This works well and I managed to get the different app environments installed on the same device manually.

The problem is in App Center I need multiple iOS builds targeting the different configurations, but App Center doesn't allow multiple builds per branch.

How do I go about setting this up in App Center without creating a branch for each environment?

Comment: Stuck on it as well, any idea how?